# os resultados da calculadora estao incorretos

Tags: javascript, html

ele captura os dois elementos mas faz a operação somente com o segundo valor do input ex: 10 + 6 ele faz 6 + 6, o problema e que eu mexi no código e não consigo voltar pra quando a soma estava correta

const operation = () => {
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputNunber')
const result = document.querySelector('.result')

```
inputs.forEach((input) => {
    const nunberInputs = parseInt(input.value)        

    let select = document.querySelector('.select')
    const indice = select.options.selectedIndex      
   
        if (select.options[indice].innerHTML === "Soma" ) {
            result.innerText = nunberInputs + nunberInputs
         
        } else if (select.options[indice].innerHTML === "Subtração") {
            result.innerText = nunberInputs - nunberInputs
           
        }else if (select.options[indice].innerHTML === "Multiplicação") {
            result.innerText = nunberInputs * nunberInputs
           
        }else if (select.options[indice].innerHTML === "Divisão") {
            result.innerText = nunberInputs / nunberInputs
           
        }       

})
```

}

const calcular = () => {
const calculo = document.querySelector('.calculo')

```
calculo.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    operation()
})
```

}

calcular()

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que analisei o problema está na sua estrutura de repetição forEach

Você tem 2 input com a mesma class chamada "inputNunber", supondo que no primeiro input seja 10 e no segundo seja 6, quando passa pelo forEach no momento da soma ele está fazendo 10 + 10 e depois 6 + 6 e dando o innerText.

Existe outras soluções melhores para chegar nesse resultado que você quer, sem a necessidade de usar o ForEach

mas para solução em seu código você pode fazer o seguinte

onde realiza as operações substitui por

```
result.innerText = parseInt(inputs[0].value) + parseInt(inputs[1].value)
```